# speeding up "pick up first string from unlist" in R

Tags: list, r, loops

I am trying to capture the first string from a list using an explicit loop, as shown in the following code:

```
for (loop.temp in (1:nrow(temp)))
    {temp[loop.temp,"drug_name_mod"] <- unlist(strsplit(temp[loop.temp,"drug_name"]," "))[1]
     print(paste(loop.temp,nrow(temp),sep="/"))
     flush.console()
    }
```

But I think it is not very efficient, anyway of improving it? Thanks!

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003527/how-do-i-specify-a-dynamic-position-for-the-start-of-substring. Standard solutions are  `lapply` over `strsplit`, `gsub` or hadley's stringr package.

Comment: It's quite similar to your earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605527/how-to-pick-up-a-set-of-numbers-from-the-end-of-lines-with-irregular-length-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First strsplit the strings, this gives you a list of string vectors, then lapply across that to get only the first element, and unlist that:

```
temp$drug_name_mod <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(temp$drug_name, " "), function(x) x[1]))
```

sapply makes it slightly simpler:

```
temp$drug_name_mod <- sapply(strsplit(temp$drug_name, " "), function(x) x[1])
```

And you can use "[" directly with 1 as its argument rather than an anonymous function:

```
temp$drug_name_mod <- sapply(strsplit(temp$drug_name, " "), "[", 1)
```