# truncate string from a certain character in R

Tags: string, r, truncate

I have a list of strings in R which looks like:

```
WDN.TO
WDR.N
WDS.AX
WEC.AX
WEC.N
WED.TO
```

I want to get all the postfix of the strings starting from the character ".", the result should look like:

```
.TO
.N
.AX
.AX
.N
.TO
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It's almost the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/3003527/168747

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Joshua's solution works fine. I'd use `sub` instead of `gsub` though. `gsub` is for substituting multiple occurrences of a pattern in a string - `sub` is for one occurrence. The pattern can be simplified a bit too:

```
> x <- c("WDN.TO","WDR.N","WDS.AX","WEC.AX","WEC.N","WED.TO")
> sub("^[^.]*", "", x)
[1] ".TO" ".N"  ".AX" ".AX" ".N"  ".TO"
```

...But if the strings are as regular as in the question, then simply stripping the first 3 characters should be enough:

```
> x <- c("WDN.TO","WDR.N","WDS.AX","WEC.AX","WEC.N","WED.TO")
> substring(x, 4)
[1] ".TO" ".N"  ".AX" ".AX" ".N"  ".TO"
```

Comment: could you possibly explain real quick how that pattern gets detected? I can't read `sub("^[^.]*", "", x)`. Thats a placeholder, then a filter with a placeholder but then what does the star do and why the empty `""` before the `x`? I can adapt the code so it works but I don't understand how it works...

Comment: It's a regular expression pattern. The first `^` matches the beginning of the string, but the next one in square brackets negates, so it matches all characters EXCEPT "." - finally the star means match that any number of times - so match everything from the start up until (but not including) the first dot. Second argument then replaces that match with an empty string.

Answer (score 14):

Using `gsub`:

```
x <- c("WDN.TO","WDS.N")
# replace everything from the start of the string to the "." with "."
gsub("^.*\\.",".",x)
# [1] ".TO" ".N"
```

Using `strsplit`:

```
# strsplit returns a list; use sapply to get the 2nd obs of each list element
y <- sapply(strsplit(x,"\\."), `[`, 2)
# since we split on ".", we need to put it back
paste(".",y,sep="")
# [1] ".TO" ".N"
```

Answer (score 0):

Strsplit might do it but in case the data set is too large it will show an error 
subscript out of bounds

```
x <- c("WDN.TO","WDR.N","WDS.AX","WEC.AX","WEC.N","WED.TO")
y <- strsplit(x,".")[,2]
#output y= TO N AX AX N TO
```