# Keep only numbers before the FIRST hyphen AND the hyphen itself

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to get rid of all the numbers/characters coming in AFTER the FIRST hyphen.
here are some examples:

```
15-103025-01
800-40170-02
68-4974-01
```

My desired output:

```
15-
800-
68-
```

I've read through posts like these:

1. [Using gsub to extract character string before white space in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895050/using-gsub-to-extract-character-string-before-white-space-in-r)
2. [truncate string from a certain character in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861740/truncate-string-from-a-certain-character-in-r)
3. [Truncating the end of a string in R after a character that can be present zero or more times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883605/truncating-the-end-of-a-string-in-r-after-a-character-that-can-be-present-zero-o)

But they are not what I'm looking for as the methods mentioned in those will get rid of my hyphen as well (leaving me only the first 2 or 3 numbers).

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
gsub(pattern = '[0-9]*-$', replacement = "", x = data$id)
grep(pattern = '[0-9]*-', replacement = "", x = data$id)
regexpr(pattern = '[0-9]*-', text = data$id)
```

but not really working as I expected.

Comment: How about `sub("(?<=-).*", "", x, perl = TRUE)`, using `sub()` for the first occurence of `-`, `(?<=-)` for a positive lookbehind to keep the `-`,  and `.*` to remove everything after it.

Comment: Hi @RichardScriven can you explain a bit more what each component mean? like "(?<=-).*"?

Comment: Refresh to see my updated my comment

Comment: @RichardScriven it works! thank you so much! so you are saying sub() can only be used for the first hyphen? waht if i now want to use the 2nd hyphen as the guide???

Comment: Then it becomes more difficult :)

Comment: @RichardScriven will sub() work still then? or will need to use a string split?

Comment: take your first attempt and just do `gsub('[0-9]*-[0-9]*$', "", x)`

Comment: Another way is `sub("^([^-]+-).*", "\\1", x)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Several ways to achieve this, here is one:

```
have <- c("15-103025-01", "800-40170-02", "68-4974-01")
want <- sub(pattern = "(^\\d+\\-).*", replacement = "\\1", x = have)
```

So in your regular expression, you'll have one group created with `()`'s, which matches the start of the string (`^`) followed by one or more numbers (`\\d+`) and the hyphen (`\\-`). Outside the group is any other character(s) that follow (`.*`).

In the replacement part, you specify `\\1` to refer to the first (and only) group of the regular expression. Not adding anything else means dropping all the rest.

Comment: hi, thank you for trying to help! may you explain a bit more what "(^\\d+\\-).*" and "\\1" mean?

Comment: You're welcome. pls see my edit for an answer to your questions.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just,

```
sub('-.*', '-', x)
#[1] "15-"  "800-" "68-"
```

To do the same with second hyphen then,

```
sub('-([^-]*)$', '-', x)
#[1] "15-103025-" "800-40170-" "68-4974-"
```

Comment: and this will guarantee to find the first hyphen??

Comment: @alwaysaskingquestions, yes. It will replace everything after the first hyphen with just a hyphen.

Comment: this is actually a very clever way to do it... what if i want to find 2nd hyphen with this?

Comment: hi sotos (for some reason cannot tag you), thank you very much for the edit! can you explain a bit on what you are doing inside the parenthesis??

Answer (score 3):

Alternative with stringr, supposedly name of vector is x

```
library(stringr)
str_sub(x,1,str_locate(x,"-")[ ,1])
```

this part takes as argument vector of strings a returns position of matched pattern in this case "-" in the string

```
str_locate(x,"-")
```

So this code will return matrix of start and end positions which in these case are the same numbers because "-" is only one character starting and ending at the same position

```
     start end
[1,]     3   3
[2,]     4   4
[3,]     3   3
```

When we subset this way

```
str_locate(x,"-")[ ,1]
```

we get

```
[1] 3 4 3
```

and now function str_sub gets substring of the whole string where we specify start and end position of substring. 
So basically it reads as for all elements of vector x make a substring starting at character 1 and end in position of first dash which is calculated as shown before.

```
str_sub(x,1,str_locate(x,"-")[ ,1])
```

Comment: hi Tomas, thank you for trying to help! was wondering if you could explain a bit more of the arguments you put in? for example, what's the two "1" you have in your code? and can this scale to locate the 2nd hyphen too?

Comment: Hi,I edited the answer to explain it. About second hyphen sure anything can be done. But I don't know if you want a string from start up to second dash or numbers from first dash until second dash

Comment: after reading your explanation, i think i understand it much better now and i think i can scale it to do 1st dash to 2nd dash myself. thank you so much!