# Remove everything before period

Tags: regex, r

I want to remove everything before period (.) sign in the following string in R. I tried with `gsub` function.

```
Test <- c("Data.A", "Data.B", "Data.C", "Data.D")
gsub("[.]", "", Test)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3003527/168747

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this: `gsub("^.*\\.", "", Test)`

What's it doing? Matches the beginning of the string with any character, any number of times. Then matches a single period. It replaces all of that with nothing.

```
> gsub("^.*\\.", "", Test)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

Answer (score 7):

Or if you find regular expressions abhorrent, you could use `sapply` and `strsplit`:

```
sapply(strsplit(Test,".",fixed = TRUE),"[[",2)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

This is splitting each element on the '.' and then grabbing just the second element of the result from each.