# Extract a certain part of a string separated with "/"

Tags: r

I have a list of file names

```
fastq/SRR17405580 
fastq/SRR17405578 
fastq/SRR17405579
```

I want to change their name to look like

```
SRR17405580 
SRR17405578 
SRR17405579
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I specify a dynamic position for the start of substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003527/how-do-i-specify-a-dynamic-position-for-the-start-of-substring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `basename()` to remove all of the path up to and including the last path separator.

```r
x <- c("fastq/SRR17405580", "fastq/SRR17405578", "fastq/SRR17405579")

basename(x)

# [1] "SRR17405580" "SRR17405578" "SRR17405579"
```

You could also use `regex`:

```r
sub('.+/(.+)', '\\1', x)

# [1] "SRR17405580" "SRR17405578" "SRR17405579"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `word` from `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
word(x, 2, sep="/")

[1] "SRR17405580" "SRR17405578" "SRR17405579"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `str_split` from `stringr` like this:

```r
library(stringr)
str_split(x, '/', simplify = TRUE)[,2]
#> [1] "SRR17405580" "SRR17405578" "SRR17405579"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws(x, whitespace = ".*/")
[1] "SRR17405580" "SRR17405578" "SRR17405579"
```